# how to create b2c telco storefront in hybris (>5.7) by modulegen?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

how to create b2c telco storefront in hybris (>5.7) by modulegen? i have tried with install.bat -r b2ctelco, but the extensions are not created in custom folder inside bin.

Thanks,
Murali

Answer (score 1):

there are specific instructions here:
https://help.hybris.com/6.0.0/hcd/f7bd6e3caca1412bb8ceb462145ba14d.html

I copied the gist below:

---

Navigate to the ${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/platform directory.

Set your ant environment by opening the setantenv.bat (Windows) or . ./setantenv.sh (Linux/Mac) file.

Run ant clean and select the default [development] environment.

Run the ant modulegen command and adjust the input.name and input.package parameters:

modulegen invocation

```
ant modulegen -Dinput.module=accelerator -Dinput.name=b2ctelcotrail -Dinput.package=de.hybris.b2ctelcotrail -Dinput.template=develop
```

**Note**

In this document, the b2ctelcotrail variable is used in various places, code and commands. If you decide on another variable make sure to use it instead.

With the three first parameters you configure the modulegen task to use the accelerator module, prefix the new extensions with the input.name value and define the default Java package prefix with the input.package value. The last parameter input.template defines to use hybris' default configuration.
Verify theAnt output in the console. Verify that the task completes successfully and lists the next steps.

**Note**

Do not follow the Next steps instructions, because the installer invoked later on overwrites the localextensions.xml file.

**Modify the installer recipe:**

By default, the Installer recipes use the standard yaccelerator template extensions. In order to use the newly created extensions you need to modify the b2c_telco recipe first:

Open the {HYBRIS_HOME} /installer/recipes/b2c_telco/build.gradle filewith a text editor.
Replace all occurrences of yaccelerator with b2ctelcotrail (or the prefix you used instead) and save the file. This way, the installer uses the newly created extensions instead of the yaccelerator template extensions when creating the localextensions.xml file and installs the b2ctelco addons on the new b2ctelcotrailstorefront. Below, you can find example recipes prior to and after editing.

**Note**

Depending on your version the actual install script may look slightly different. Make sure to use the script provided with your Commerce Suite and do not copy the contents from the examples below.

*Before: HYBRIS_HOME/installer/recipes/b2c_telco/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'installer-platform-plugin'
apply plugin: 'installer-addon-plugin'
apply plugin: 'installer-coreplus-plugin'
def config = {
    localProperties {
        property 'subscription.client.endpoint.uri', 'http://localhost:9001/hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web/sub/cisSubscriptionMock'
        property 'persistence.engine.mongodb.databaseName', 'entitlements'
        property 'cis.client.subscription.mock', 'false'
        property 'kernel.events.cluster.jgroups.channel', 'disable'
        property 'datahub.publication.saveImpex', ''
        property 'commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience', 'desktop'
        property 'kernel.autoInitMode', 'update'
    }
    extensions {
        extensions {
            extName 'acceleratorcms'
            extName 'addonsupport'
            extName 'b2ctelcocheckoutaddon'
            extName 'b2ctelcocockpits'
            extName 'b2ctelcostore'
            extName 'b2ctelcostorefront'
            extName 'cissubscription'
            extName 'cissubscriptionatddtests'
            extName 'commercesearchbackoffice'
            extName 'commerceservicesbackoffice'
            extName 'emsclient'
            extName 'emsui'
            extName 'entitlementstorefront'
            extName 'entitlementatddtests'
            extName 'mcc'
            extName 'solrfacetsearchbackoffice'
            extName 'solrserver'
            extName 'configurablebundleatddtests'
            extName 'subscriptionstorefront'
            extName 'subscriptionatddtests'
            extName 'subscriptionserviceshmc'
            extName 'subscriptionbackoffice'
            extName 'yacceleratorstorefront'
            extName 'yacceleratorcockpits'
            extName 'yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess'
            extName 'yacceleratorcore'
            extName 'customersupportbackoffice'
        }
        webApp {
            contextRoot 'entitlements-web'
            path '${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../hybris-ems/binary/entitlements-web.war'
        }
        webApp {
            contextRoot 'hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web'
            path '${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../hybris-sbg/binary/hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web.war'
        }
    }
}
def pl = platformFactory.createPlatform config
void modifySubscriptioncockpitsRequiredExtensions() {
    def extensioninfoFile = "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/ext-commerce/subscriptioncockpits/extensioninfo.xml"
    def root = new XmlParser().parse(extensioninfoFile)
    def required = root.extension[0].children()
    def dependency = required.find { node -> node.@name == 'yacceleratorcockpits'}
    if(dependency == null) {
        def node = new Node(null, 'requires-extension', [name: 'yacceleratorcockpits'])
        required.add(0, node)
        new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(extensioninfoFile))).print(root)
    }
}
task setup << {
    modifySubscriptioncockpitsRequiredExtensions()
    pl.setup()
    pl.project.addons {
        names "b2ctelcostorefront,b2ctelcocheckoutaddon"
        b2c "yacceleratorstorefront"
        platform pl
    }
    pl.project.addons {
        names "entitlementstorefront"
        b2c "yacceleratorstorefront"
        platform pl
    }
    pl.project.addons {
        names 'subscriptionstorefront'
        b2c 'yacceleratorstorefront'
        platform pl
    }
    copy {
        from "${installerHome}/recipes/b2c_telco/logback.xml"
        into "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/lib"
    }
    copy {
        from "${installerHome}/recipes/b2c_telco/sbg_properties"
        into "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/lib"
        exclude "**/*.txt"
    }

}
ext {
    host = "http://localhost:9001"
    contextRoot = "entitlements-web"
    tenant = "single"
    config = {
        localProperties {
            properties(
                    'tomcat.generaloptions': '-Xmx3096M',
                    'standalone.javaoptions': '-Xmx3040M'
            )
        }
    }
}

task initialize << {
    pl.build()
    pl.initialize()
}
task start << {
    pl.startInBackground()
}
task stop << {
    pl.stopInBackground()
```

*After: HYBRIS_HOME/installer/recipes/b2c_telco/build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'installer-platform-plugin'
apply plugin: 'installer-addon-plugin'
apply plugin: 'installer-coreplus-plugin'
def config = {
    localProperties {
        property 'subscription.client.endpoint.uri', 'http://localhost:9001/hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web/sub/cisSubscriptionMock'
        property 'persistence.engine.mongodb.databaseName', 'entitlements'
        property 'cis.client.subscription.mock', 'false'
        property 'kernel.events.cluster.jgroups.channel', 'disable'
        property 'datahub.publication.saveImpex', ''
        property 'commerceservices.default.desktop.ui.experience', 'desktop'
        property 'kernel.autoInitMode', 'update'
    }
    extensions {
        extensions {
            extName 'acceleratorcms'
            extName 'addonsupport'
            extName 'b2ctelcocheckoutaddon'
            extName 'b2ctelcocockpits'
            extName 'b2ctelcostore'
            extName 'b2ctelcostorefront'
            extName 'cissubscription'
            extName 'cissubscriptionatddtests'
            extName 'commercesearchbackoffice'
            extName 'commerceservicesbackoffice'
            extName 'emsclient'
            extName 'emsui'
            extName 'entitlementstorefront'
            extName 'entitlementatddtests'
            extName 'mcc'
            extName 'solrfacetsearchbackoffice'
            extName 'solrserver'
            extName 'configurablebundleatddtests'
            extName 'subscriptionstorefront'
            extName 'subscriptionatddtests'
            extName 'subscriptionserviceshmc'
            extName 'subscriptionbackoffice'
            extName 'b2ctelcotrailstorefront'
            extName 'b2ctelcotrailcockpits'
            extName 'b2ctelcotrailfulfilmentprocess'
            extName 'b2ctelcotrailcore'
            extName 'customersupportbackoffice'
        }
        webApp {
            contextRoot 'entitlements-web'
            path '${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../hybris-ems/binary/entitlements-web.war'
        }
        webApp {
            contextRoot 'hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web'
            path '${HYBRIS_BIN_DIR}/../../hybris-sbg/binary/hybris-cis-mock-subscription-web.war'
        }
    }
}
def pl = platformFactory.createPlatform config
void modifySubscriptioncockpitsRequiredExtensions() {
    def extensioninfoFile = "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/ext-commerce/subscriptioncockpits/extensioninfo.xml"
    def root = new XmlParser().parse(extensioninfoFile)
    def required = root.extension[0].children()
    def dependency = required.find { node -> node.@name == 'b2ctelcotrailcockpits'}
    if(dependency == null) {
        def node = new Node(null, 'requires-extension', [name: 'b2ctelcotrailcockpits'])
        required.add(0, node)
        new XmlNodePrinter(new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(extensioninfoFile))).print(root)
    }
}
task setup << {
    modifySubscriptioncockpitsRequiredExtensions()
    pl.setup()
    pl.project.addons {
        names "b2ctelcostorefront,b2ctelcocheckoutaddon"
        b2c "b2ctelcotrailstorefront"
        platform pl
    }
    pl.project.addons {
        names "entitlementstorefront"
        b2c "b2ctelcotrailstorefront"
        platform pl
    }
    pl.project.addons {
        names 'subscriptionstorefront'
        b2c 'b2ctelcotrailstorefront'
        platform pl
    }
    copy {
        from "${installerHome}/recipes/b2c_telco/logback.xml"
        into "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/lib"
    }
    copy {
        from "${installerHome}/recipes/b2c_telco/sbg_properties"
        into "${suiteHome}/hybris/bin/platform/tomcat/lib"
        exclude "**/*.txt"
    }

}
ext {
    host = "http://localhost:9001"
    contextRoot = "entitlements-web"
    tenant = "single"
    config = {
        localProperties {
            properties(
                    'tomcat.generaloptions': '-Xmx3096M',
                    'standalone.javaoptions': '-Xmx3040M'
            )
        }
    }
}

task initialize << {
    pl.build()
    pl.initialize()
}
task start << {
    pl.startInBackground()
}
task stop << {
    pl.stopInBackground()
}
```

**Run the modified installer script**

Navigate to the {HYBRIS_HOME} /installer directory.
Invoke the Installer with the b2c_telco recipe:

```
WINDOWS: install.bat -r b2c_telco
UNIX: ./install.sh -r b2c_telco
```

The install script creates a new localextensions.xml file using the newly created b2ctelcotrail extensions and also installs the addons required by B2C Telco into the new b2ctelcotrailstorefront extension.
Check your {HYBRIS_HOME} /hybris/config/localextensions.xml file and verify that it contains the b2ctelcotrail extensions instead of the yaccelerator template extensions.
You will also need to make the following change in order for your Telco site to start correctly.

In the file **/b2ctelcostorefront/resources/b2ctelcostorefront/web/spring/b2ctelcostorefront-web-spring.xml** you need to change the entry

```
<bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="de.hybris.platform.yacceleratorstorefront.security.StorefrontLogoutSuccessHandler">
```

to:

```
<bean id="logoutSuccessHandler" class="de.hybris.b2ctelcotrail.storefront.security.StorefrontLogoutSuccessHandler">
```

This is to overcome a known bug in the build process that will be fixed in a forthcomig release.

---

There are a few more steps (so best to look at the wiki for more details), but this should help with the initial problems.

Hope this helps,
Sebastian